Rollup: plugin-node-resolve generates .js files outside the desired folder
I have a yarn/lerna monorepository with diferent packages. I want to bundle the package called "react-native" which is a library component.
I configured my rollup.config.js and everything seems to work fine until I use the nodeResolve() from the @rollup/plugin-node-resolve.

As you can see without the plugin the js and d.ts files are in the correct location (or at least the one I want)
but when I use the node-resolve plugin it seems to take the full path (react-native/src) inside dist in order to generate the .js files.

I can't figure it out what I an doing wrong.
this is my rollup config:
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser'
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel'
export default {
  input: ['src/index.ts'],
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'esm',
    sourcemap: true,
    preserveModules: true
  },
  external: ['react/jsx-runtime', 'react', 'react-native', '@expo/vector-icons', 'expo-font'],
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    commonjs(),
    copy({
      targets: [{ src: 'src/assets', dest: 'dist' }]
    }),
    typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
    terser()
  ]
}

and this is my tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.
